# Dihedral extension of $\mathbb Q$ with small discriminant

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, number-fields

Let $K$ be a fixed quadratic number field, say $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt 5)$. For any integer $n \geq 3,$ I would like to build a number field $D_n$ such that $D_n/\mathbb Q$ is Galois, with Galois group isomorphic to $D_{2^{n-1}}$ (dihedral group of order $2^n$), $K \subset D_n$ and with small discriminant.

I know class field theory could help me here, since I'm basically trying to construct a cyclic extension of $K$ with conditions on the ramification but I am not too familiar with its use.

Proposition 1 of this article of [Louboutin, Park and Lefeuvre](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0e11/c2a38549117d86cc2c7e1cd3dec42b5e44d8.pdf) gives me exactly what I need, provided I can find a subgroup $H$ of $\mathcal I_K(\mathfrak{m})$ (= the group of fractional ideals prime to $\mathfrak{m}$) containing $P_{K, \mathbb Z}(\mathfrak{m})$ (= the subgroup of $\mathcal I_K(\mathfrak{m})$ of principal ideals of the form $(\alpha)$, with $\alpha \equiv a$ mod $\mathfrak{m}$, for some $a \in \mathbb Z$ prime with $\mathfrak{m}$) such that $\mathcal I_K(\mathfrak{m})/H$ is cyclic of order $2^n$, for some modulus $\mathfrak{m}$ which is invariant under conjugation of $K/\mathbb Q$, and having small enough prime factors.

In the case $K = \mathbb Q(\sqrt 5)$, the class number is one, so we can see non-zero fractional ideals of $K$ as elements of $K^{\times}$ up to units of $\mathcal O_K$. I have been told to look for modulus given by primes $p \equiv 1$ mod $2^n$ which split in $K$, i.e. $\left(\frac{5}{p}\right)=1$, but I still have no idea how to show that such a subgroup $H$ exists.

Comment: Find a prime ideal $ P$ of norm $N(P)=1+2^{n+l}r$. Let $S=\{a^in O_K,a^{2^lr}\equiv 1\bmod P\}$. Find representatives $J_c$ of the classgroup such that for every product $\prod_i J_{c_i}$ if it is principal then it is generated by an element $\in S$. Let $(\eta_c)=J_cJ_{c^{-1}}$ and $H=\{\frac{aJ_c}{\eta_c},a\in J_{c^{-1}}\cap S\}$. Then $I_K(P)/H$ is generated by $(g^{2^lr})$ where $g$ is a generator of $O_K/P^\times$. Classfield theory says there is an abelian extension $L/K$ with $(\frac{I}{L/K})=\sigma^m$  for any ideal $I \in (g^{2^l r})^m HH^{-1}$

Comment: What does your construction look like when $K$ has class number one, like in the case of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 5)$ ? I have a hard time following what you are doing.

Comment: For the PID $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ let a prime number $p \equiv 1 \bmod 2^n$,
$P$ a prime ideal of $O_K$ above $p$ then $O_K/P$ is a field with $1+2^{l+n}r$ elements, then $G = \{ \frac{a}{b}O_K, a\in O_K - P, b \in O_K -P\}$, $H = \{ \frac{a}{b}O_K, a\in O_K, a^{2^l r} \in 1+ P, b \in O_K , b^{2^l r} \in 1+ P\}$ are groups of fractional principal ideals and $G/H$ is cyclic with $2^n$ elements generated by $g^r O_K$ for $g\in O_K$ a generator of $(O_K/P)^\times$. The whole ideal group is $\mathcal{I}_K=P^\Bbb{Z} G$.

Comment: Thanks. Did you mean $g\mathcal{O}_K$ for a generator of $G/H$ ? Are you suggesting taking the subgroup $P^{\mathbb Z}H$ then ? Unfortunately I think this subgroup does not contain $P_{K, \mathbb Z}(\mathfrak{m})$, so how do I know the extension I get from class field theory is dihedral over $\mathbb Q$ ?

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is looking for quadratic number fields ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{5p})$ for prime numbers $p$. If the $2$-class group, which is cyclic, has order $2^n$, then the Hilbert $2$-class field has the dihedral group of order $2^{n+1}$ as its Galois group, and it contains ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{5})$. Examples (computed using pari)

- ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{5 \cdot 29})$: $h = 4$, $f = x^4 - x^3 - 5x^2 - x + 1$
- ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{5 \cdot 521})$: $h = 8$, $f = x^8 - 2x^7 - 47x^6 - 86x^5 + 97x^4 + 182x^3 - 76x^2 - 88x + 32$
- ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{5 \cdot 461})$: $h = 16$, $f = x^{16} - 7x^{15} - 21x^{14} + 300x^{13} - 635x^{12} - 1740x^{11} + 9231x^{10} - 9852x^9 - 15316x^8 + 44515x^7 - 30235x^6 - 7230x^5 + 12209x^4 + 1057x^3 - 1769x^2 - 430x - 25$
- ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{5 \cdot 12301})$: $h = 32$; pari can compute the polynomial using the command quadhilbert(5*12301).

Similarly, using complex quadratic number fields ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{-5p})$ for primes $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ gives you the following examples:

- ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{-5 \cdot 19}$: $h = 8$,
  $f = x^8- x^6 + 2x^5 + 3x^4 - x^3 - x^2 - x - 1$;
- ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{-5 \cdot 179}$: $h = 16$, $f = x^{16} + 5x^{15} + 13x^{14} - 164x^{13} + 608x^{12} - 1165x^{11} + 1192x^{10}
   - 404x^9 - 357x^8 + 220x^7 + 263x^6 - 97x^5 - 308x^4 + 292x^3 - 106x^2 + 17x - 1$
  ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{-5 \cdot 659}$: $h = 32$, and pari gives you the corresponding polynomial.